# Observable repeatWhen & retryWhen other observable is true (network is connected)

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, angular2-observables

**Example code:**

```
const networkConnected = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

setTimeout(networkConnected.next(true), 10000);

webSocket('ws://localhost:4949')
  .pipe(
    retryWhen(errors => errors.pipe(delay(10000), filter(() => networkConnected.value === true))),
    repeatWhen(completed => completed.pipe(delay(10000), filter(() => networkConnected.value === true))),
    tap(a => console.log('Connecting...'))
  ).subscribe(
    message=> console.info(message),
    error => console.error(error),
    () => console.warn('Completed'),
  );
```

I searched for one hour and wasnt able to find one other person who want the same.

There is a WebSocket which should be reconnected whenever it loses the connection.
So I integrated a `retryWhen`. The `repeatWhen` is for the case that the WebSocket completes...

And now I want to add a logic to only reconnect (retry/repeat) when the internet connection is OK.
So when my `networkConnected` observable is `true`.
When it's `false` the reconnect (retry/repeat) should wait until its true.

Maybe something with `zip`? Or `mergeMap`?
Or I add a `timer` which runs every second and check if the value is true with `skipUntil`.

But I think someone of you have a better solution

Comment: 'the reconnect (retry/repeat) should wait until its true' - does this imply that the entire websocket should not be subscribed until `networkConnected` emits true?

Answer (score 0):

I would have the networkConnectivity be a precondition for the websocket to be set up:

```
networkConnected
  .pipe(
    // do not want to re-open the websocket when the network is still connected
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    // when connected open the websocket, otherwise noop and wait till connected
    switchMap(isConnected => isConnected ? openWebsocket() : empty())
  )
  .subscribe(
    message=> console.info(message),
    error => console.error(error),
    () => console.warn('Completed')
  );

openWebsocket = () => {
  return webSocket('ws://localhost:4949')
    .pipe(
      // this works for websocket errors while networkConnected=true
      retryWhen(errors => errors.pipe(delay(10000)),
      repeatWhen(completed => completed.pipe(delay(10000)),
      tap(a => console.log('Connecting...'))
    );
};
```

Comment: And when the network connectivity switches to `offline` the retryWhen will only delay it 10 seconds and thats it. Isnt it possible to say "retryWhen networkStatus becomes true"?

Comment: @Patrick given that the `networkConnected` is a precondition for opening a websocket it would not make sense to retry opening the connection as long as networkConnected=false. I updated my answer to account for that scenario as well. Hope this helps